# for loop inside function for creating a table in an ms word document?

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I'm trying to create a table in an ms word document from js. I have the foundations down but my issue is that I need to loop through a certain number of times determined by a previous variable to create that many table rows. And within each table row, the table cells have different values stored in arrays that must be looped through. However, it appears that a simple for loop doesn't match the syntax. Are there any alternatives?

Here's my code:

```
function wordDoc() {
    const doc = new docx.Document();
    const table = new Table({
        rows: [
            new TableRow({
                children: [
                    new TableCell({
                        children: [new Paragraph("Number")],
                    }),
                    new TableCell({
                        children: [new Paragraph("Details")],
                    }),
                ],
            }),
            //this where the error occurs:
            for(i = 0; i< numberOfNumbers; i++){
                new TableRow({
                    children: [
                        new TableCell({
                            children: [new Paragraph(numbers[i])],
                        }),
                        new TableCell({
                            children: [new Paragraph(details[i])],
                        }),
                    ],
                }),
            },
        ],
    });

    docx.Packer.toBlob(doc).then(blob => {
        saveAs(blob, "Page.docx");
    });
}
```

Here's the error message:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'for'`

Comment: Now knowing Jscript, I suspect you need to create a substructure OUTSIDE the table declaration, THEN insert it into that place. You can't just stick a for loop in the middle of the table declaration.

Comment: @KaseyChang Sorry I'm quite new to js and am confused on how exactly that would work? If you don't mind, could you elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: I believe you need to do declare a new row then APPEND more rows to newrow, then finally, append newrow to the new table. As I said, I don't know JScript, I'm going off my knowledge of JavaScript.